# Unit testing a dataflow/apache beam pipline that takes a side input

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

Using Dataflow 2.1 sdk

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
            <version>[2.1.0, 2.99)</version>
        </dependency>
```

As per [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/#side-inputs) documentation `setSideInputInGlobalWindow` should be available. But I only see below two relevant functions:
[image]

Below is my full code:

```
DoFnTester<EventItem,EventItem> fnTester = DoFnTester.of(myDoFn);
    TestPipeline pipeline = TestPipeline.create();

TableRow row= new TableRow();
        atr.set("a", 7);
        atr.set("q", new ArrayList<String>() {{ add("video_referrer"); add("from_homepage");}});

PCollectionView<TableRow> sideInput =  (PCollectionView<TableRow>) pipeline.apply(Create.of(Arrays.asList(atr)));
        Iterable<TableRow> sidVal = Arrays.asList(atr);
        fnTester.setSideInput(sideInput, sidVal); //error on this line

        List<Foo> testOutputs = fnTester.processBundle(Arrays.asList(testInput));
```

I see `setSideInput(PCollectionView<T> sideInput, BoundedWindow window, T value)` function [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.2.0/). But in this case how do I get `BoundedWindow`
Any ideas what am I missing here, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using GlobalWindow.INSTANCE but generally DoFnTester is targeted to be deprecated, and the recommended way is to always use TestPipeline and PAssert.

Comment: jkff, thank for reply. Any ideas if there is an updated documented on this (Using TestPipeline to test individual DoFn's)

Comment: I think PAssert and TestPipeline have javadocs; also, nearly all transforms in the SDK itself are tested using TestPipeline, so you should be able to use Beam's own unit tests as examples. Let me know if something in particular remains unclear after that.